# Calculate time difference in percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make some statistical data on the performance of a specific task.

One of the data points gathered is how long time it took to run. I'd then like to compare that against the expected time to run and thereby know in percentage if the task performed better or worse than expected.

See example below:

[image: Example]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since Super User is not a formula/script writing service, it would be best if you share with us what formula you have already attempted so we can help you solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula on cell `C3` should be:

```
=(B3/$B$2)-1
```

Copy down this formula to cells C2, C3, C4 and so on.

Select column C, right-click and select Cell format -> Percentage

Comment: So simple, thanks. My own attempts where much more complicated.